# How to make search filtering and sorting at the same component in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sorting, vuejs2, filtering

I'm trying to filter and sort an array at the same time. Expecting to edit the same initial array. Having the UI of a search input and two selects, first one with sorting by type (price/rate), and the second with ascending/descending sorting. So the searching works fine, but when it comes to sorting the main filtered array `filtered` isn't sorted. It happens while I'm watching for data. But the sorting doesn't work.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="nav">
      Sort by:
      <select v-model="type">
        <option value="none">none</option>
        <option value="price">price</option>
        <option value="rating">rate</option>
      </select>
      <select v-model="direction">
        <option value="min-to-max">Ascending</option>
        <option value="max-to-min">Descending</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      Filtering by name:
      <input type="text" v-model="search" />
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="elements">
      <template v-for="item in filtered">
        <div class="item" :key="item.id">
          <strong class="name">{{ item.name }}</strong>
          <div class="price">{{ item.price }}</div>
          <div class="rating">{{ item.rating }}</div>
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HomePage",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { id: 1, name: "First", price: 100, rating: 0.2 },
        { id: 2, name: "Second", price: 101, rating: 0.5 },
        { id: 3, name: "Third", price: 101, rating: 0.9 },
        { id: 4, name: "Forth", price: 50, rating: 0.6 },
      ],
      search: "",
      price: false,
      rate: false,
      asc: true,

      type: "none",
      direction: "min-to-max",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filtered() {
      // works fine
      return this.items.filter((i) => {
        return i.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
      });
    },
    propsAB() {
      return `${this.type}|${this.direction}`;
    },
  },
 methods: {
    sortByPriceAsc() {
      this.filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.price - b.price;
      });
    },
    sortByPriceDesc() {
      this.filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.price - a.price;
      });
    },
    sortByRateAsc() {
      this.filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.rating - b.rating;
      });
    },
    sortByRateDesc() {
      this.filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.rating - a.rating;
      });
    },
  },
  watch: {
    propsAB(newVal, oldVal) {
      const [oldPropertyA, oldProvertyB] = oldVal.split("|");
      const [newPropertyA, newProvertyB] = newVal.split("|");
      if (this.newPropertyA === "price" && this.newProvertyB === "min-to-max") {
        this.sortByPriceAsc();
      } else if (
        this.newPropertyA === "price" &&
        this.newProvertyB === "max-to-min"
      ) {
        this.sortByPriceAsc();
      } else if (
        this.newPropertyA === "rating" &&
        this.newProvertyB === "min-to-max"
      ) {
        this.sortByRateAsc();
      } else if (
        this.newPropertyA === "rating" &&
        this.newProvertyB === "max-to-min"
      ) {
        this.sortByRateDesc();
      } else return;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Vue 2's reactivity system doesn't detect array mutation, so sorting has to be done like `this.arr = this.arr.sort()`. This is because Vue 2 uses getters/setters on the instance to detect changes, and thus only top-level assignments are detected, not mutations. Read more: [Reactivity in Depth | Vue 2](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html), and specifically the [sections on objects and arrays](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays).

Comment: Pardon me for an odd question, isn’t it a vue3 syntax also?

Comment: Well, are you using Vue 2 or Vue 3? Vue 3 uses Proxies. If your are using 3, there is a minor issue with the `key` attribute in the template, by the way. Sorry if I have assumed incorrectly; the patterns you are using seemed to indicate Vue 2.